# A module $B$ is flat if Tor $= 0$

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

From Weibel's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra":

Exercise 3.2.1: An $R$-module $B$ is flat if Tor$_i^R(A,B) = 0$ for every $R$-module A.

It seems to me that the obvious way to do this would be to use the definition:

Tor$_i^R(A,B) = $H$_i(P.\otimes B)$ where $P.$ is a projective resolution of A.

We need to show that for an exact sequence:

$...\rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow A_{n} \rightarrow A_{n-1} \rightarrow ...$ ,

$...\rightarrow A_{n+1} \otimes B \rightarrow A_{n} \otimes B \rightarrow A_{n-1}  \otimes B \rightarrow ...$ is exact.

Since we can only access exactness via the definition of Tor, it seems to me that we might have to construct a projective resolution around this point in the sequence, however I am currently struggling.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's enough to show that for any _short_ exact sequence $$0\to A_1\to A_2\to A_3\to 0$$ we have $$0\to A_1\otimes B\to A_2\otimes B\to A_3\otimes B\to 0$$exact. At least, that is the definition of "flat" that I know (I seem to recall that the translation between the two isn't all that difficult, and short exact sequences are often nicer to work with)..

Comment: Yeah you're right, we can work with short exact sequences. Although I still have a problem! Thanks

Comment: Check the horseshoe lemma, then the snake lemma.

Comment: That looks like it should do it! Every time I saw an instance of the question I asked it was always phrased in such a way that made it look like a nice simple question, however this proof is certainly not a simple rearranging of definitions.

Comment: It is possible that there are more elementary solutions, but if those lemmas are available to use why not use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We want to show that $\_ \otimes B$ is exact. Now Lets take for this a short exact sequence $$0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0$$
Now lets apply the functors $\mathrm{Tor}^i(\_,B)$ to that sequence. Now this gives by the definition of $\mathrm{Tor}^i(\_,B)$ as a homological functor a long exact sequence $$ ... \to \mathrm{Tor}^1(X,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^1(Y,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^1(Z,B) \to\mathrm{Tor}^0(X,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^0(Y,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^0(Z,B) \to 0  $$
Now  since we have a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Tor}^0(Z,B) \cong Z\otimes B$ we may rewrite the top sequence as:
$$ \mathrm{Tor}^1(X,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^1(Y,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}^1(Z,B) \to X\otimes B \to Y\otimes B \to Z \otimes B \to 0  $$
But since $ \mathrm{Tor}^1(Z,B)=0$ this becomes:
$$0\to X\otimes B \to Y\otimes B \to Z \otimes B \to 0  $$
as desired.
(for the other direction of the implication just observe that if $B$ is flat, the projective resolution stays exact after tensoring and hence the higher $\mathrm{Tor}$-terms vanish)

Comment: This is the kind of nice answer I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: you are very welcome! one just has to love long exact sequences!

Comment: @Daven In some sense, the $\operatorname{Tor}$ functor's _purpose_ is to measure (an to some extent fix) the fact that tensoring isn't left-exact. So, when you have a module where tensoring in fact _is_ left exact, $\operatorname{Tor}$ gives you $0$. Similarily, the $\operatorname{Ext}$ functor measures the non-exactness of $\operatorname{hom}(B, -)$, in the other direction (and even for $\operatorname{hom}(-, B)$, if you just remember to turn all the arrows the right way).